# Vs code shows red and yellow in UI while using React

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I try to use react and it runs without any errors. But, Vs code shows red and yellow underline.

It happens only I use react.

[image]

Comment: And have you checked what they're trying to tell you? What's your _question_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe they said " 'import' is only available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6'). (W119)jshint(W119)"

Comment: OK, so are you using some kind of JSHint plugin? Have you read its docs to find out how to configure it for the right esversion as the message tells you?

Comment: I don't know to configure it. I am just clone the repo and i get those errors.

Comment: So, _do_ you have a JSHint plugin installed? The repo seems to use ESLint and Prettier: https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template/blob/3a96c33d167684a1ca5eb1759f920f63b43e7f5c/package.json#L52-L55

Comment: Yes. I already installed. Now, rechecked

Comment: Well you should either configure or disable it if you don't want to see those warnings.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe . It solved by adding configuration.